# How to send all data in one buffer through serial port?

Tags: c#, serial-port

My existing code:

```
private void ConvertAndSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (serialPort.IsOpen)
    {
        byte[] TxBuffer = new byte[240];
        string[] coords = textBox1.Text.Split('\n');
        for (int i = 0; i <= coords.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (coords[i].Length > 0)
            {
                Data = GetValue(coords[i]);
            }
        }
        TxBuffer[0] = 0x5A;
        TxBuffer[1] = Instruction;
        TxBuffer[2] = (byte)Data.Length;
        Data.CopyTo(TxBuffer, 3);
        TxBuffer[Data.Length + 3] = 0x2C;
        serialPort.Write(TxBuffer, 0, 4 + Data.Length);
    }
}
```

Now I am sending every "Data" in separate "Txbuffer". e.g. if I have more than one "Data", I am going to send more than one "Txbuffer". ***How can I combine all "Data" into one "Txbuffer" and send at one time?***

Comment: Why do you think it matters?  The device driver will concatenate them all into a single FIFO buffer anyway, as long as `Write()` is called again before the last byte is sent, and serial ports are so slow, that's easy to do.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @BenVoigt  It is not a big issue but it would be more  efficient.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't exactly "wrong", although a magic number like `240` doesn't win any prizes.  You can also use BinaryWriter, pass the SerialPort.BaseStream to its constructor.

Keep in mind that serial ports implement streams, not 'packets'.  Just a raw train of bytes with no distinctive beginning and end.  Just like TCP.  There is no framing protocol unless you create your own.  Which you did.  It is up to the receiver to turn the stream of bytes back into a frame.  That same requirement doesn't exist when you transmit it.